# IF Block crashing?

Tags: batch-file, if-statement, cmd, syntax-error, batch-processing

I apologize for my incompetence, as I am just starting out with batch, but this IF block crashes my program every time it runs with the syntax incorrect error. I can't find an error, can anyone help?

```
echo What is the scale of this conflict? (Determines length of game) 
echo 1. Small (Quick)
echo 2. Medium (Normal)
echo 3. Large (Extended)
SET /P difficulty="Type 1, 2, or 3, then press ENTER:"
IF %DIFF% == 3 (
set /a troops = %random% %%52 +45
set cities = 10
)
IF %DIFF% == 2 (
set /a troops = %random% %%32 +25
set cities = 6
)
IF %DIFF% == 1 (
set /a troops = %random% %%17 +10
set cities = 3
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no `DIFF` variable.May be you need this:

```
echo What is the scale of this conflict? (Determines length of game) 
echo 1. Small (Quick)
echo 2. Medium (Normal)
echo 3. Large (Extended)
SET /P difficulty="Type 1, 2, or 3, then press ENTER:"
IF %difficulty% == 3 (
set /a troops = %random% %%52 +45
set cities = 10
)
IF %difficulty% == 2 (
set /a troops = %random% %%32 +25
set cities = 6
)
IF %difficulty% == 1 (
set /a troops = %random% %%17 +10
set cities = 3
)
```

Comment: This worked! Thanks, I felt I was overlooking something simple like that :)